# org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder in Android?

Tags: android, import, uri

Unable to import import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder; in android. Can anyone tell me why?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.u.g.c"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I had already been using the   `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` . But still I am unable to import it.

Comment: can you post your build.gradle file

Comment: done, please see updated version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your gradle version is not updated

```
android {
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

}
this only works if you are using gradle 1.3.0-beta2 or greater, so you will have to add this to buildscript dependencies if you are on a lower version:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0-beta2'
```

Add below line too in your gradle file

```
 compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
```

Comment: My file had ,         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

Comment: which line of code required this import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder

Comment: https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563309b6778daf02acc0a508/operations/56406930e597ed20c8d8549c
Trying to implement this, the Java version. I have the subscription key

Comment: @UrviG I have edited my answer you can add dependency I mentioned in my answer I have tested it myself and it will resolve your error

Comment: Yes it did, Thank you !! :)

Comment: accept my answer if it helped you in resolving your problem

Comment: When I run it, i am getting the Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE
 File1: C:\Users\Administrator\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpmime\4.3\5b0002c5fb66867ca919be0fbd86de1cfaf76da7\httpmime-4.3.jar
 File2: C:\Users\Administrator\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpclient-android\4.3.5.1\eecbb0b998e77629862a13d957d552b3be58fc4e\httpclient-android-4.3.5.1.jar

Answer (score 0):

**Apache http has been deprecated in api 23.**

For android studio add this line in build.gradle

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Another way is,

Find `org.apache.http.legacy.jar` which is in `Android/Sdk/platforms/android-23/optional`, add it to your dependency.

Comment: I was using this tag, still there is error. Please see my build.gradle in the question.

Comment: @UrviG Add below lines in your gradle.   compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'

Comment: thank you, I added. Still in the import line i am getting "cannot resolve URIBuilder"
My imports 
`import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder`

Comment: @UrviG Please added jar file of http client and added compile files libs in gradle like this.  compile files('libs/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar')
   compile files('libs/httpmime-4.0.3.jar')